# Ignore jest test unless explicitly triggered

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs

I have integration testing that sends me an email. I have written a jest test that tests this feature, but I only want it to run if I explicitly run that test: I don't want to receive an email every time I start VS Code.

I don't want to mock the email service, because success for this test is the email arriving in my inbox.

Is it possible to have jest ignore a test unless it is explicitly triggered?  Eg in VS Code clicking the "Debug" codelens button.

If not, what are some techniques for managing tests like this?

Comment: Jest is for automated testing, There aren't conventional techniques for that because this isn't automated testing, the success depends on user actions (checking an inbox). A suitable approach for e2e testsis to mock parts that cause undesirable side effects. In this case it's mail server. If you want to make sure it really sends a mail in the test, set up mocked mail server like https://www.npmjs.com/package/fake-smtp-server but you're not limited to JS tools for that.

Comment: Any way, you can have some test files that are normally ignored (testPathIgnorePatterns config) but can run explicitly `jest some.unsafe-test.js` or with custom npm script like `test-unsafe` that uses a different Jest config that includes unsafe tests.

Comment: Using a different config file sounds like it might be a winner, I'll look into that!  Thanks